# How to show graphically selecting an item after a button is clicked from listview in android?

Tags: android, drawable

I have list view which lists out items and I have disabled the touch on selection too. I have a button - when I click on next the second item in the list is selected but there is no graphical way to show that the second item is selected?

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: "the list is selected but there is no graphical way to show that the second item is selected? " - Are you talking abut listitem selection effect?

Comment: Yep. That is right. For example: If I touch the selected item in the listview it comes up with orange color or something - which confirms that I have selected the item.. same way I would like it to show when I click the button.. and also orange color shouldn't disappear?